# CSS Transitions: order of firing when multiple transitions

Tags: html, css

[demo](https://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/mwmERM)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#"><span>text insie span</span> |||| text inside anchor</a>
```

**SASS**

```
span {
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

a {
  transition: all 5000ms ease;

  &:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

When hover, first 5000ms transition is fired on `<a>` ignoring `<span>`.

After it finished, fires 500ms transition on `<span>`

Why it happens? Shouldn't they start simultaneously? Why `<a>` delays `<span>`'s transition by its own duration?

Comment: The span tag is nested within the a tag, which means the parent element styles will be applied first.

Comment: I still don't see why the delay. @Kyle1323

Comment: Are you trying to get them to fire at the same time and both be red?

Comment: please try not to write `all` in transition, it's meaningless

Comment: @vsync Of course it is not meaningless if you know what it does and used properly.

Comment: @LGSon - been coding in CSS since 90's brother. I wrote hundreds of thousands of CSS lines of code and never in my life had to use the `all` word.

Comment: @vsync I'm on my 23rd year of coding and wrote millions of lines of code, still, it is not a meaningless property value for the reason I gave.

Comment: @LGSon - there wasn't CSS 25 years ago.. statistically `all` is unsued, i'm sure you can agree on that

Comment: @vsync CSS started in 1994, with a norwegian guy ... same time as I started, a loooong time ago :) ... and yes, I agree it is rarely used

Comment: @vsync thanks for advice, but it's a demo so shouldn't really matter whether to use `all` or specific property transition :). I see you had a nice discussion with LGSon :)))

Comment: yep, pretty nice discussion, we are basically brothers now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `span` doesn't have a `:hover` rule of its own, the browsers handles this different.

Chrome simply picks up the `anchor`'s, but in Firefox it actually runs the `span`'s first and then the `anchor`'s override it.

I can't say which one is correct here, as there is both a property inheritance involved and to not be able to animate the same property on an element with to different rules.

If you add a `:hover` rule to the `span`, you'll see it work as expected

*Note, you need to hover the `span` or else nothing happens with its transition*

Stack snippet

```css
span { 
  color: pink;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
span:hover { 
  color: lime;
}

a {
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>text inside span</span> |||| text inside anchor</a>
```